# php postgresql concat hyperlink with fields

Tags: php, postgresql, pg, pg-query

How to concat hyperlink in php postgresql query? I tried this but confused with single and double quotes.

```
$query = "SELECT im.id AS \"ID\",
          im.type AS \"TYPE\",
         CONCAT('<a href=\"\" onclick=(\"'".im.id."'\)">Click</a>')
FROM instancemaster im
WHERE imd = "."'$imd'";
```

My problem is the CONCAT part getting syntax error.

I tried like this, as I have innerjoin as well where 'im.id' table alias is conflicting with php concatenation.

```
CONCAT('<a onclick=\"', ".im.id.", '\">', Click, '</a>')
```

Comment: Concat like glues text together? I don't see any comas in your CONCAT, try `CONCAT('<a href=\"\" onclick=(\"' , im.id , '\")>Click</a>')`  and if your imd is just an integer then you can use `WHERE imd =$imd;`

Comment: No problem, can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat like glues text together. I don't see any comas in your CONCAT, try

```
CONCAT('<a href=\"\" onclick=(\"' , im.id , '\")>Click</a>')
```

and if your imd is just an integer then you can use

```
WHERE imd =$imd;
```